# Replacing Namespace using xslt not producing expected result

Tags: xslt

I wish to replace the namespace v1 in the following xml from http://choby.co.xx/DialogueServices/AM/V1 to http://choby.co.xx/XYZ/WM/V1

```
Input
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v1="http://choby.co.xx/DialogueServices/AM/V1">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <v1:CancelAppointmentRequest>
     <Loc>1</Loc>
  </v1:CancelAppointmentRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Expected:
<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:v1="http://choby.co.xx/XYZ/WM/V1">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <v1:CancelAppointmentRequest>
     <Loc>1</Loc>
  </v1:CancelAppointmentRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

xslt used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://choby.co.xx/XYZ/WM/V1"
xmlns:ns1old="http://choby.co.xx/DialogueServices/AM/V1">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" />
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:element name="soapenv:{local-name()}"   namespace="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns1old:*">  
<xsl:element name="ns1:{local-name()}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Result:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
 <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <ns1:CancelAppointmentRequest xmlns:ns1="http://choby.co.xx/XYZ/WM/V1">
 <Loc>1</Loc>
 </ns1:CancelAppointmentRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The Header and Body namespace is different from Envelope

Comment: The Header and Body namespace is different than the Envelope because you are specifying a different namespace in your template match for `/*` when you re-construct the `soapenv:*` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://choby.co.xx/XYZ/WM/V1"
xmlns:ns1old="http://choby.co.xx/DialogueServices/AM/V1">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" />

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[namespace-uri()='http://choby.co.xx/DialogueServices/AM/V1']">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://choby.co.xx/XYZ/WM/V1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The stylesheet copies everything without change except elements with namespace `http://choby.co.xx/DialogueServices/AM/V1`. Such elements are modified.

Comment: How to remove ns xmlns:v1="http://choby.co.xx/DialogueServices/AM/V1" from the Envelope?

Comment: The namespace definition should not make any problem for standards aware processors. It is just defined at the top level and used at the right place. I'm afraid there is no standard way how to influence namespace definitions of XSLT1.0 output. It is processor dependant.